# How to tidily restore a sandstone fireplace

Tags: fireplace, stone, hearth

I would really appreciate some advice in regards to the best solution to restore a stone fireplace that was previously covered by plasterboard.

I am looking to fit a log burning stove into the hole, however I would like to restore as much of the old fireplace as possible.  The plasterboard has been applied so it protrudes the fireplace (see attached picture), can anyone recommend a tidy way to create a neat edge between the sandstone and plaster?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks.

Iain

Comment: The back of a log stove can get hot enough to char wood, so if this is not an outside wall, you should replace the insulating layer of fire brick which seems to have been partially removed.

Answer (score 1):

Cut back the plaster evenly and use a fancy stone trim piece. You can use a tile saw to miter the corners, use paintable caulk where the plaster meets the trim, to hide irregularities. Use construction adhesive, or silicone, or tile mortar, to adhere the trim to the sandstone. Your biggest job will be cleaning up the sandstone and brick.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It would be great for looks, but it may not be worth it to get it working. Putting Fire Brick back in is one thing, but how's the chimney. A gas fireplace (piped or tanked) might be the only cost effective solution.

Other that, you'd cut back the plaster to reveal the full brick up to the mantel shadow. Then, you can add framing members to terminate the plaster on the sides & can bridge the side lumber with lumber to support a new mantel.

I hope you can restore the look, it would be a real plus.